# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, apache-spark-2.0, scala-2.11

I am running a spark application using yarn in cloudera.
Spark version: 2.1

I get the following error:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/data/yarn/nm/filecache/13/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.10.2-1.cdh5.10.2.p0.5/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 18/04/14 22:20:57 INFO
>   util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM 18/04/14 22:20:57
>   INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP 18/04/14
>   22:20:57 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.conf.YarnConfiguration     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.(ApplicationMaster.scala:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:764)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:763)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: @hayat please review the answer below

Comment: I had the same pb and i have made an exlude to force use of cluster lib. configurations { runtimeonly {         exclude group: 'org.apache.spark'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by verifyning that the spark version configured in SPARK_HOME variable matches the hadoop version installed in cloudera.
From the following link https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html you can download the suitable version for your required hadoop.
The haddop version in cloudera can by found by:

```
$ hadoop version
```

Comment: This can happen even when your version of SPARK locally is different from the target version. Be particularly carefuly when there are many installations on the same box, that your SPARK_HOME is pointing exactly to the same version as the server.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue while trying to start a Spark job using Yarn Rest API.
And the reason was that the environment variable SPARK_YARN_MODE was missing. Adding this env var, everything works fine :

```
export SPARK_YARN_MODE=true
```